# add ads.txt on reactjs (optimized and dockerized build)

Tags: reactjs, ads, google-ads-api, adsense, google-ads-script

I deployed inside a docker a reactjs project (optimized build).

I added the required scripts to enable Google ADS but I got following message

[image]

It doesn't find the ads.txt file, I put it under the /public folder and re-built and re-deployed the docker but nothing.. do you have any suggestion for it?

Comment: If you attempt to access https://[your-domain]/ads.txt, do you see your file?I just tried using the domain in the screen shot, and got an error handling page, so it seems the file might not be there. Or you've got some other handler kicking in, and redirecting that request to your error page.

Answer (score 0):

The ads.txt file does not affect your site's acceptance in AdSense.

Comment: If the file cannot be found, ads will not be displayed on the domain.

Comment: If the file is available at /ads.txt-  ads will be visible.

If the ads.txt file is showing - but there is also a file missing message - then the ads will still be visible.